# Dynamically use latest version of Flutter package hosted in GitHub?

Tags: flutter, dart, github, flutter-packages, pubspec

TL;DR: After building an app, is there a way to dynamically get the newest reference of a given Flutter package which is hosted in a GitHub repository?

---

Let's say I create a Flutter package, hosted in a GitHub repository. The package can be anything, like a button implementation.

In my Flutter project I reference this package in `pubspec.yaml`

```yaml
cool_button:
    git:
      url: git@github.com:my_user/cool_button.git
      ref: main
```

I build the app and publish it to Android and iOS.
Then, I make some changes and commit it to the button package repository, like change some borders, shadows, color...

What I want is that when the user access the published app, it references those new commits and creates the button with the new changes that I've made. Something like a code push, or a micro-service update.

The idea is to be able to commit new changes to the package and the app, in production, get those changes. It would affect the app without submitting a new release.

Thing is, currently when I reference the repository in pubspec and run `flutter pub get`, Flutter get a reference of the latest commit in the branch, and doesn't seem possible to change it later

After run the `flutter pub get`:

```yaml
* cool_button 1.0.0+1 from git git@github.com:my_user/cool_button.git at cb215b
```

And `pubspec.lock` has

```
cool_button:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      path: "."
      ref: HEAD
      resolved-ref: cb215b186a03632eede189cd3b26bbea1fbfe9c0
      url: "git@github.com:my_user/cool_button.git"
    source: git
    version: "1.0.0+1"
```

Is there a way that I can dynamically get the newest commit of the package?
Is there any other way that I can approach this problem?

Comment: "like change some borders, shadows, color..." If you're just making minor cosmetic changes like those, then you don't really need code push and instead could make your app retrieve those values dynamically from somewhere.  Otherwise, I think that pushing native code is prohibited by Apple and Google app stores.

Comment: I think Firebase Remote Config could solve your problem for dynamical changes. But, as I know there are no options of doing that dynamically by using GitHub packages, since you're still going to have to download these changes through `flutter pub get`

Comment: @jamesdlin The idea of changing the border, shadow or color is just an example. But imagine that the app could reference a widget of the package, and this widget would be able to add anything to the page. I could make a commit where this widget would return a column with a bunch of data, and make another commit to change it to return just an image, a button, a text...

Comment: @isac-moura In this case the remote config wouldn't help. I could reference some property, but not a whole widget structure.

Comment: "Is there any other way that I can approach this problem?" Is this equivalent to a CDN for a Flutter app that will show new content? If so you could abstract out the layout and widgets into a schema that is understood by the app. It can read the schema from a web endpoint, parse it, and build the view using pre-defined widgets.